# Formspree: error message | Can't send an empty form

Tags: html, forms, contact-form

I've searched on google but I couldn't get anywhere. I've added the Formspree contact form to a website and after initial set up it worked. After I activated and confirmed my email I sent one more email just to be sure it's up and running and when I click send I receive an error message. [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQboH.png)

This is what the html code looks like

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Q7H.png)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm relatively new to web development so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem occurred due to absence of `name` attribute in the `input` fields of the form. It is also given on the "Integration" section of the forms you created in the `formspree.io`.
It says `Finally, ensure that each input has a name attribute.`

Answer (score 0):

Im wrestling with this right now. What browser/OS are you running? My form is currently working in Chrome on OS X, but Safari gives me that error.

Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: I did not try a different browser, and guess what it does work in Chrome! However Safari still nothing. I think I might just figure out how to do this properly via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on Formspree's website:

> - You are using an old Safari version, Safari mobile or some other
>     browser that is not recent Chrome, Firefox or Edge. In this case you
>     could have been a victim of an old HSTS policy we had on Formspree
>     that didn't allow sites to post content to non-https versions of
>     Formspree. In this case please change your form's action= attribute to
>     https://formspree.io/your-email.